# jenkins: how to capture stderr output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In jenkins, you can run a script with [`sh()`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script).  There is an options to `returnStdout`, which will send `stdout` to a return value, rather than printing it to the console.

Is it possible to capture `stderr` in any way?  Whether through an option to the function or through some workaround?

Answer (score 15):

Generally, you can [redirect a process's STDERR to STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)#Redirecting_to_and_from_the_standard_file_handles) with `2>&1` and collect both.

There's no other way but this redirection workaround at the moment, see  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44930